# Import a .p12 cert to GPG for signing debian packages

Tags: debian, code-signing, pgp, gnupg, pkcs#12

I am currently signing some debian `.deb` packages with a self-signed PGP certificate, which I obtained from a collegue. Hence I have the following files in my folder `~/.gnupg/:

- gpg.conf (Currently only comments)
- pubring.gpg
- random_seed
- secring.gpg
- trustdb.gpg

I now obtained a properly signed certificate in .pfx format (or a .p12 exported from Keychain) which I should use to sign my debian packages. I have been looking on Google for quite a bit to figure out, how to convert the certificate. What I am looking for at the moment is an easy way to convert the .pfx to the file structure above, so that I can continue signing my debian packages with the new certificate.

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X.509 infrastructure and OpenPGP are two different technologies. You can't convert X.509 certificate to OpenPGP key (though you can use the the keypair from the certificate for a new OpenPGP key).

Comment: I have note yet figured out how to create such an OpenPGP key. When I use `gpg --gen-key` I basically create new new self-signed key pair and I don't have an option to refer to an existing keypair.

Comment: @Besi Reusing keys is possible from format point of view, but I don't know if it's possible to do this with GnuPG.